# Copy the contents of a document(s) through FileDialogbox picker, to a new one

Tags: vba, ms-word

With MS_Word 2010 I have been trying to achieve the way to copy the contents(whole) of one file to a new one retrieving the file name of the original and adding it to the new one with the suffix "Copy".

All this process has a reason, since the Original document has only a few editable section and have protection enable (And I cant disable it) but I need to review it with other macro, so with a Copy of the contents in a new document I have been able to apply my whole macro. I also know of the ***method CopyFile*** but since this method copy also the characteristic of the original doc (the constrains in edit) I decide not to use it.

Searching around and using the recorder(for the copy actions) i have been able to come with this:

```
Sub Backup()
Dim DocName As String
Dim DocPath As String

'Declare a variable as a FileDialog object.
Dim fd As FileDialog

'Create a FileDialog object as a File Picker dialog box.
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

'Declare a variable to contain the path of each selected item. Even though the path is aString, the variable must be a Variant because For Each...Next,  routines only work with Variants and Objects.
Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant

'Use a With...End With block to reference the FileDialog object.
With fd

    'Allow the user to select multiple files.
    .AllowMultiSelect = True

    'Use the Show method to display the File Picker dialog box and return the user's action.
    'If the user presses the button...
    If .Show = -1 Then
        'Step through each string in the FileDialogSelectedItems collection.
        For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
        On Error Resume Next

            'vrtSelectedItem is aString that contains the path of each selected item. You can use any file I/O functions that you want to work with this path.
            'MsgBox "Selected item's path: " & vrtSelectedItem

            'Retrieve the name of the current doc (later I found out about .Name, .Path, .FullName ...)
            Dim fso
            Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            DocName = fso.GetBaseName(vrtSelectedItem)
            'MsgBox "Selected item's : " & DocName

            'Retrieve the path without the filename/extention
            Documents.Open(vrtSelectedItem).Active
            DocPath = ActiveDocument.Path
            'MsgBox "Selected item's path: " & DocPath

            'Copy the content of the current document
            'With Documents(DocName)
            With ActiveDocument
                .WholeStory
                .Copy
            End With

            'Create Backup File with ability to modify it, since the original is protected by password and only few segments are enable to edit
            Documents.Add Template:=DocName & "Copy", NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0

            'Since Document.Add its suppose to promp as the Active document
            'Paste the contents and save
            'With Documents(DocName & "Copy")
            With ActiveDocument
                .PasteAndFormat (wdUseDestinationStylesRecovery)
                .SaveAs DocPath
            End With
            'Documents(DocName & "Copy").Close SaveChanges:=True

        Next
    'If the user presses Cancel...
    Else
    End If
End With
'Set the object variable to Nothing.
Set fd = Nothing
End Sub
```

But as you guess, it doesn't work as desire and don't create the copy neither the new document with the name. So any scope in the right direction will be appreciate.
Thanks in advance for all the answers.

---

For future reference here is the code improved, based in the Response of *@Charlie*

```
Sub Backup()
Dim DocName As String
Dim NewDoc As Document

'Declare a variable as a FileDialog object.
Dim fd As FileDialog

'Create a FileDialog object as a File Picker dialog box.
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

'Declare a variable to contain the path of each selected item. Even though the path is aString, the variable must be a Variant because For Each...Next,  routines only work with Variants and Objects.
Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant

'Use a With...End With block to reference the FileDialog object.
With fd

    'Allow the user to select multiple files.
    .AllowMultiSelect = True

    'Use the Show method to display the File Picker dialog box and return the user's action.
    'If the user presses the button...
    If .Show = -1 Then
        'Step through each string in the FileDialogSelectedItems collection.
        For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
        On Error Resume Next

            'vrtSelectedItem is aString that contains the path of each selected item. You can use any file I/O functions that you want to work with this path.
            'MsgBox "Selected item's path: " & vrtSelectedItem

            'Retrieve the name of the current doc (later I found out about .Name, .Path, .FullName ...)
            Dim fso
            Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            DocName = fso.GetBaseName(vrtSelectedItem)
            'MsgBox "Selected item's : " & DocName

            'Create Backup File with ability to modify it, since the original is protected by password and only few segments are enable to edit
            Set NewDoc = Documents.Add

            'Since Document.Add its suppose to promp as the Active document
            'Paste the contents and save
            With NewDoc
                Selection.InsertFile FileName:=vrtSelectedItem, Range:=vbNullString, _
                ConfirmConversions:=False, Link:=False, Attachment:=False
                .SaveAs FileName:=vrtSelectedItem & "_BACKUP.docx"
                .Close
            End With

        Next
    'If the user presses Cancel...
    Else
    End If
End With
'Set the object variable to Nothing.
Set fd = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try creating a new Word doc then using this line to "insert the text from the protected Word doc." It's the same as going to the Insert Ribbon tab -> Object -> Text from File.

```
Selection.InsertFile FileName:="protected.docx", Range:="", _
    ConfirmConversions:=False, Link:=False, Attachment:=False
```